# Pytest, How do you test a function and not run the rest of the file

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest: I have a file large .py file with a main body and many functions.  Without editing it to another file how do you focus on a function and only test it without running or executing the whole .py file

Comment: by commenting the functions that you don't want to test ?

Comment: By not calling the other functions?

Comment: Using the `-k` option when calling `pytest`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the function/class name after the file name with two colons. e.g.

`pytest test_abc.py::test_function`

If you want to execute multiple functions/classes with pytest, you need to mention it separately. e.g.

`pytest test_abc.py::test_function1  test_abc.py::test_function2`